# Error when send value to text box of ChildForm From diagbox

Tags: vb.net, parent-child, send

I wants send value to text box of ChildForm  From diagbox

Error : **System.MissingMemberException: 'No default member found for type 'TextBox'.'**

My code:

```
    Private Sub SimpleButton1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles SimpleButton1.Click
    For Each frm As Form In Application.OpenForms
        If frm.IsMdiChild Then
            If frm.Name = "FRM_3_213_1_BBT_TIENICH_CARD_YAMAHA_INPUT" Then
                CallByName(frm, "TextBox1", CallType.Set, "Text", "AAAAAAA")
            End If
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Can someone please help me resolve this issue? Thanks is advance.
[image]

[image]

Comment: Dear  Md. Suman Kabir ! 
I was edit my question with image add. 
i want send string "AAAAAA" from Dialog to textbox1 in Child Form("FRM_3_213_1_BBT_TIENICH_CARD_YAMAHA_INPUT")

Comment: CallByName is a default fuction of visual studio. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/callbyname-function

Comment: You should not use `CallByName` unless absolutely necessary, which pretty much means never. What is the relationship between these two forms? if we know that then we can explain the proper way to achieve your aim. You say that the target is an MDI child and the source is a dialogue. Where is the dialogue being opened from and how exactly is it being opened? Is the dialogue being closed when this change is to be made or will it stay open.

Comment: If you were going to use `CallByName`, that's not how you'd use it. The first argument should be the target object, so that would be the `TextBox`, not the form. The second argument should be the member, so that would be `"Text"`. The fourth and later arguments should be the arguments for the call, so that should be the text you want to assign.

Comment: That said, while I've never used `CallByName` myself because code that uses it is usually garbage - I've written garbage code but not for that reason - maybe this would work: `CallByName(frm, "TextBox1.Text", CallType.Set, "AAAAAAA")`.

Comment: The dialog is MDI child form(A). When i click button on This MDI child form (A) the dialog open and i input string and i want string send to this MdI child form(A).

Comment: Dear John ! 
I try CallByName(frm, "TextBox1.Text", CallType.Set, "AAAAAAA" but unsuccessful
Please show me another way can do that. 
P/S I  was edit my question with image add

Comment: You should update the question and provide a FULL and CLEAR explanation. I asked how you were displaying the dialogue, i.e. `Show` or `ShowDialog`, and whether the dialogue was closing when this text is to be written back because those details will affect how it is best done.

Comment: You know what the type of the form is that you’re looking for. Far easier to cast the frm object to the correct type and access the text box directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work

```
    Private Sub SimpleButton1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles SimpleButton1.Click
        For Each frm As Form In Application.OpenForms
            If frm.IsMdiChild Then
                If frm.Name = "FRM_3_213_1_BBT_TIENICH_CARD_YAMAHA_INPUT" Then
                    Dim t As TextBox
                    t = CType(frm.Controls("TextBox1"), TextBox)
                    t.Text = "AAAAAAA"
                End If
            End If
        Next
    End Sub
```

The reason your code does not work is that a generic Form object does not have "TextBox1" property. You can make CallByName work if you cast frm object into a specific form type that has the textbox control.

You can also try

```
CallByName(frm.Controls("TextBox1"), "Text", CallType.Set, "AAAAAAA")
```